# An amplifier that can output 40..50 V at around 15 MHz

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm trying to build something to amplify a signal to produce a 40 V output at 15 MHz.

I haven't been successful in finding an opamp that can both output at these voltages while also not dropping the gain (around 20x) at these frequencies. Is there any opamp that can do this?

If not, how should I go about tackling this problem?

This is for a wireless charging unit I am trying to make, based on magnetically coupled resonators. I am working on the transmitter, which needs to power a coil with a boosted AC signal (a sine wave). I believe the load impedance should be around 50 ohms, although I am new to amplification and electronics in general so I might be wrong.

Comment: You should probably be looking for an RF power amplifier rather than an op-amp.

Comment: just look for opamps in a parametric search: GBW product 300 MHz, Slew rate 5000 V/us. There are probably some high speed current-feedback opamps that can do this. if only the supply voltage is a problem: use an output step-up transformer

Comment: Load impedance is essential here. Also, is that voltage pk-pk or RMS?

Comment: @mkeith I just updated the post, let me know if there's anything else I add to clear things up and thanks for the help!

Comment: For a wireless charging transmitter, you don't need an amplifier, you need a power oscillator, built round the transmit coil. This is a totally different beast to an amplifier, and much easier to get the required power